# Recursions of Sequences of Length $n$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to determine a recursion $a(n)$ that describes the number of $n$ digit ternary sequences without any blocks $012$ occurring and another recursion $b(n)$ that counts the number of sequences with $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ as possible letters that contain an even number of $0$'s and of $1$'s.  I am not sure how to approach these sorts of recursions and any instructive responses would be much appreciated!

Comment: In the future, if you have two separate questions, please ask them in separate posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problems like this, I define recurrences for each type of string of interest.  The second is easier.  Define $EE(n)$ as the number of strings of length $n$ with an even number of $0$'s and $1$'s, $EO(n)$ as the number of strings of length $n$ with an even number of $0$'s and an odd number of $1$'s, and $OE(n), OO(n)$ as you would guess.  Then $EE(n+1)=2EE(n)+EO(n)+OE(n)$ as to get an even-even string you can start with an even-even string and add a $2$ or $3$, an even-odd string and add a $1$, or an odd-even string and add a $0.$  You can write recurrences for each of the others.

For the first, you are interested in progress toward $012$.  So you would want B(n) to be sequences ending in $1$ or $2$ that are not $01$ or $012$, $C(n)$ to be sequences ending in $0$, $D(n)$ to be sequences ending in $01$ and the sum of these is the result you want.

Comment: Thank you!  The only thing I am still not clear on then is how the initial conditions would work as you have set up these recursions.  I find your reasoning helpful though, is it usually possible to split up the recursions into cases like this and take the sum?

Comment: For initial conditions you just count them.  $OO(1)=0, EE(1)=OE(1)=EO(1)=1$.  I find this a good way to keep track of the constraints.  You can make the various values into a vector and the recurrence into multiplying by a matrix.  This allows using the formalism of diagonalizing and eigenvalues/eigenvectors to solve the recurrence.

Comment: @mjD:  You are correct, I missed the $3$.  I'll fix.  I can't edit the comment any more, but yes, $EE(1)=2$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thank you! The only thing I am still not clear on then is how the initial conditions would work as you have set up these recursions. I find your reasoning helpful though, is it usually possible to split up the recursions into cases like this and take the sum?

Comment: @JamesDoe:  splitting the recursions is a technique to keep track of the constraints.  I have found it works well for combinatorial problems.  You have to find a set of recursions that capture the problem and thinking about how you can extend a string of length $n$ to one of length $n+1$ finds many of the solutions.  For the initial conditions, see my first two comments-basically you count small ones by hand.  It should be clear how I got the values.